# How to allow a git hook to run an executable with sudo by modifying /etc/sudoers

Tags: linux, git, sudo, executable

I'm using a git post-update hook to run a command via sudo, and I get the error: `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`. I believe I need to modify `/etc/sudoers` but I don't know how to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the line

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

in your `sudoers` file, comment it out.

Comment: Thanks! What exactly does this do? Could it have any unintended consequences?

Comment: If set, sudo will only run when the user is logged in to a real tty. When this flag is set, sudo can only be run from a login session and not via other means such as cron(8) or cgi-bin scripts. This flag is off by default. http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html